# Create .bat with command tempate

Tags: batch-file

How do I create a .bat file that has a command template where I can just fill in the parameters to execute?  Example:
`template.bat`
`C:\Users\> C:\Python27\python.exe cursor_is_here`

So, I want the Python text to be filled out so I can just type in the python file.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do this in a way similar to this (if I understood you correctly)

*template.bat*

```
@echo off
C:\python27\python.exe %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Then you call `template.bat foo.py`, the parameter `foo.py` is appended as `%1` to what you wrote into the batch. If you provide more parameters they go into %2, %3, ...

Comment: much easier: `C:\python27\python.exe %*` gives all parameters, may be there one or a dozend.

Comment: @Stephan you are correct, but I intentionally started on a beginner level. The question is about basics, because of that I started small